# Three.js: Merging geometries and materials from loaded objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a basic Collada model made in Blender which consists of two parts internally. A canopy and a trunk, each with it's own texture. The object is very low poly; using a few faces for the canopy with a transparent texture and a 3 sided cone for the trunk.

Obligatory but perhaps not very relevant picture:
[Trees in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7N3o.jpg)

However, I'd like there to be lets say 200 of these trees which obviously is very inefficient in terms of rendering when adding them by `scene.add()`. I have been cloning the source object which is neat, but understandably this doesn't help much when it comes to rendering performance.

I understand that a good way around this slowdown is to add all of the objects as one by merging the geometry and materials into one big old forest object. I know this can normally be done outside of code, by making a forest in Blender and exporting that instead, but I am procedurally placing the trees go in the code itself (mazes!), plus I would like to introduce more complicated objects once past this hurdle. I have seen a lot of examples for doing this in code with cubes, spheres and the occasional monkey head, but am struggling to find anything for dealing with imported objects.

Lastnight I started going through my imported objects to see if I could mirror the steps for grabbing geometry and material info on load (referenceRef is the obj.scene response of the Collada loader here)

```
resourceRef.traverse(function(child) {
   if (child.geometry !== undefined) {
      // ooh a shape!
      // lets merge this with any other geometries in the
      // object, collect all of the materials too and then
      // when we need a new tree, position it (?) and 
      // merge it with the forest geometry (??) and re-apply
      // the 2 materials (???)
   }
}
```

And then I realized that this seems a tad messy, with multiple geometries and materials to consider and me being new to Three.js.

It might be the best way to handle this but I am after confirmation of this really. There may be a much better, simpler or built in way for creating instances of potentially more complicated, textured and loaded objects that I'm missing (I hope so!).

Any pointers on the best way of handling this would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What I understand is that you are asking for a practise on how to handle the loading and usage of assets, not actual code? Do you know about ThreeJS `LoadingManager`s?